# Boxplot and xyplot overlapped

Tags: r, lattice, boxplot, bwplot

I've done a conditional boxplot with my data, with the `bwplot` function of the `lattice` library.

```
    A1 <- bwplot(measure ~ month | plot , data = prueba,
              strip = strip.custom(bg = 'white'),   
              cex = .8, layout = c(2, 2),
              xlab = "Month", ylab = "Total",
              par.settings = list(
                box.rectangle = list(col = 1),
                box.umbrella  = list(col = 1),
                plot.symbol   = list(cex = .8, col = 1)),
              scales = list(x = list(relation = "same"),
                            y = list(relation = "same")))
```

Then, I've done a xyplot because I want to add the precipitation data to the previous graph, using `xyplot` from `lattice` library also.

```
    B1 <- xyplot(precip ~ month | plot, data=prueba,
   type="b",
   ylab = '% precip',
   xlab = 'month',
   strip = function(bg = 'white', ...)
     strip.default(bg = 'white', ...),
   scales = list(alternating = F,
                 x=list(relation = 'same'),
                 y=list(relation = 'same')))
```

I've try to draw them on the same graph using `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra` library:

```
    grid.arrange(A1,B1)
```

But with this, I don't overlap the data, but the result is this
[image: boxplot and xyplot]

How could I draw the precipitacion data "inside" the boxplots conditioned by plot?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `barley` data as Andrie did, another approach with `latticeExtra`:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

bwplot(yield ~ year | variety , data = barley, fill = "grey") +
xyplot(yield ~ year | variety , data = barley, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Pascal. It seems very simple and easy, but it doesn't work with my data. I have use bwplot(...) + as.layer(xyplot(...)), but it only draws the bwplot, without giving any error.

Comment: Why to use `as.layer()`? There is no `as.layer()` in the example. And as you are trying to plot at the same time totals and percentage, I am not really surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I have used `as.layer()` because without it, and error said `Error in as.layer(lay) : argument "lay" is missing, with no default`.

Comment: Anyway, now I've tried again without `as.layer()` and the error didn't appear, all appear to work properly, but it only draws the first plot (if I use first `bwplot` it draws it, and if I use first `xyplot` it only draws it

Comment: Sure, `% Precip` is 33 times bigger than `Total`.

Comment: Of course!!!! I don't know where is my mind, I'm sorry. I have divided by 10 the precipitation data and now it works perfectly fine. I'm very grateful @Pascal

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom panel function.  I demonstrate with the built-in `barley` data:

Imagine you want to create a simple `bwplot` and `xyplot` using the `barley` data. Your code might look like this:

```
library(lattice)

bwplot(yield ~ year | variety , data = barley)
xyplot(yield ~ year | variety , data = barley)
```

To combine the plots, you need to create a panel function that first plots the default `panel.bwplot` and then the `panel.xyplot`.  Try this:

```
bwplot(yield ~ year | variety , data = barley,
       panel = function(x, y, ...){
         panel.bwplot(x, y, fill="grey", ...)
         panel.xyplot(x, y, col="red", ...)
       }
)
```

[image]

---

There is some information about doing this in the help for `?xyplot` - scroll down to the details of the `panel` argument.

Comment: I need to understand how the panel function works properly, I'll try. Thanks for your answer.